# How do vortex filaments move?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In fluid dynamics (Navier-Stokes, incompressible case), a vortex filament, as I understand it, is a curve of points $x\in\mathbb R^3$ such that the velocity field $v\colon \mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$ is parallel to its curl, $\nabla \times v$, also known as the *vorticity*. In other words, for each time $t$ we have a curve $\gamma_t\colon (a,b)\to\mathbb R^3$ that satisfies 
$$v(\gamma_t(s),t)=\lambda_{s,t}\nabla\times v(\gamma_t(s),t),$$
for some $\lambda_{s,t}\in\mathbb R$.

What is the equation governing the movement $d\gamma_t/dt$ of the vortex filament $\gamma_t$?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You need to specify which media the vortex filaments is in otherwise there's no answer. i.e. quantum and classical description were quite different.

Comment: Thanks. Does it work with that edit I did?